# Product Not Currently Available

Tags: magento-1.9, product, checkout, simple-product, inventory

So recently we've noticed a problem with newly created products within our magento site.  It is a configurable product with multiple sizes and colors associated to it. We have full inventory for the product, it displays correctly on the product page you can add it to your cart which is great.  But, once the product is in the cart it displays an error message under the product "The requested quantity for "item name" is not available, selected option(s) or their combination is not currently available.

I have checked inventory, it has 200, it is enabled and in stock but for some reason the cart won't check right.

It's not only happening to new products but it's happening to products that have been established but we add a new color to the item and we see the same problem.

images attached to show both front end and back end. (note: image in the cart does not reflect actual product but displays configurable image)

Thank you

[image][image]

Comment: try running a full reindex process and see if problem persists. If a reindex fixes it, then you should check that your cron is running

Comment: I ran a full re-index and the problem persisted.